# sql server group by with an alias

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am new to sql server, transitioning from mysql.

I have a complicated case statement that I would like to group on 6 whens and an else.  Likely to get larger.  To be able to run it, I need to copy the statement into the group by each time there is a modification.  In mySql I would just group by the column number.  Is there any work around for this?  Making the code very ugly.

Is there going to be a performance penalty in creating a sub query for my case, then just grouping on the result field.  Seems like trying to make the code more elegant will cause the query to use more resources.

Thanks

Below is a field I am grouping on.  As I make a modification to the field for more edge cases, then I need to change code in up to 3 places.  Makes for some very ugly code, and I need no extra help doing that myself.

```
dz_code = case 
      when isnull(dz.dz_code,'N/A') in ('GAB', 'MAB', 'N/A')  and dc.howdidyouhear = 'Television' then 'Television'
      when isnull(dz.dz_code,'N/A') in ('GAB', 'MAB', 'N/A')  and dc.howdidyouhear in ('Other', 'N/A') then 'Other'
      WHEN dz.dz_code = 'irs,irs' THEN 'irs'
      when dz.dz_code like '%SDE%' THEN 'SDE'
      when dz.dz_code like 'referral,' then REPLACE(dz.dz_code, 'referral','')
      when charindex(',',dz.dz_code) = 4 then left(dz.dz_code,3)

    else
      dz.dz_code
    END,
```

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are asking without seeing some code, but it sounds like you should use subquery and then use the alias in a group by.

Comment: Show us your query. otherwise, no idea what you are asking?

Comment: This is an example of logic I am usingdz_code = case 
      when isnull(dz.dz_code,'N/A') in ('GAB', 'MAB', 'N/A')  and dc.howdidyouhear = 'Television' then 'Television'
      when isnull(dz.dz_code,'N/A') in ('GAB', 'MAB', 'N/A')  and dc.howdidyouhear in ('Other', 'N/A') then 'Other'
      WHEN dz.dz_code = 'irs,irs' THEN 'irs'
      when dz.dz_code like '%SDE%' THEN 'SDE'
      when dz.dz_code like 'referral,' then REPLACE(dz.dz_code, 'referral','')
      when charindex(',',dz.dz_code) = 4 then left(dz.dz_code,3)

    else
      dz.dz_code
    END,

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can wrap the query in a subquery and use the alias in the select and the group by. It looks a little bulky in this example, but if you've got more complex case switches, or more than one of them, then this solution will probably much smaller and more readable.

```
select
  CaseField
from
  (select
    case when 1 = 2 then
      3
    else 4 end as CaseField
  from
    YourTable t) c
group by
  CaseField
```